Wiring ceiling light fixture, box has 3 sets of cables
My ceiling box has 3 sets of wires:

One set brings power from the panel

One set is a carrier to fixtures beyond the ceiling box

One set is to the switch


I have wired in a new light fixture as follows, but the breaker blows as soon as I switch it on:

Connected all four ground wires and nutted them off.

Connected the incoming and outgoing white wires with the white wire from the fixture and nutted them off.

Connected the incoming and outgoing black wires with the white wire (taped it black) from the switch and nutted them off.

Connected the black wire from the switch to the fixture's black wire and nutted them off.


What did I do wrong?
Edit:
The switch has a red wire, but not the ceiling box. In order to have other lights work in the bedroom and bathroom, every night I’ve been connecting the two black wires and the two white wires, leaving the switch out of it. This allows all the other lights to work with their dedicated switches.
Response to RMDman:
As to the three sets of cables in the box:
• I identified the incoming by using a tester. It beeped and turned red. All the others got a solid green light.
• To find the carrier, I connected (one at a time) each remaining cable to the hot cable (line?).
•• The first one, presumably the switch cable, did not light up the rest of the lights in the room.
•• The connection with the other cable (load?) resulted in lighting up the rest of the room.

you mean 3 cables, not sets of wires, each cable has wires in it

Connected the incoming and outgoing black wires with the white wire (taped it black) from the switch and nutted them off. is the problem

Can you add a picture of the inside of the box to your post? How certain are you that you correctly identified where each cable runs to? Can you double-check at the switch that it has only a single cable with only a black and a white wire?

I believe your original should have had 3 nutted grounds, the incoming black nutted to the switch black, the switch white nutted to the outgoing black (and marked black at both ends), the outgoing white nutted to the incoming white.  If you added another light/load, the wires for those should have been nutted to the same ones for the existing light—assuming the new light is to be switched by the same switch.

The white wire you have connected to the black wires is a neutral and is creating a direct short.
You need to first verify that you have a black and a white at the switch ( creating a switch loop, now not allowed by code.)  Then verify that the white wire that you have bringing in power is indeed the correct wire connected with blacks in the ceiling box.
It is a matter of making sure you have the correct white wire. With multiple wires it is easy to get them mixed up.
